Start at the second view of the NavigationStack in SwiftUI with a back button
See the same question using UIKit with images! I'm trying to do the same thing in SwiftUI, where the user starts at SecondView() with the FirstView() lower in the navigation stack; but haven't been able to find out how to programmatically push at the NavigationStack without having to custom manage stack states. Right now, I have something like this:
NavigationStack {
  FirstView()
}
.onFirstAppear {
  // Code that pushes SecondView() to the NavigationStack
}

(OnFirstAppear is a custom extension that runs the first time the view gets rendered.)
Is there any way to do this so that

It looks to the user as if SecondView() is where the route starts - meaning no animations
Has a back button on the SecondView() that takes the user to the FirstView()
Preferably not custom-manage states.


Why don't you want to "custom manage stack states"?

Use a navigation path and set a default value

SwiftUI views are driven by state. You may read how NavigationStack (and UINavigationController) works. It's not magic, it's state, aka NavigationPath.
